# Anychart Gantt time in seconds which resets to zero

Tags: javascript, anychart

Hello I am creating a gantt chart in seconds to calculate the time of a robot line.
I use the [Anychart library](https://docs.anychart.com/Gantt_Chart/Overview). When I get to 60 seconds it goes back to zero and resets my tooltip.
[image]
I retrieve the values ​​using a JSON file and I use this file to write the diagram

```
  <html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body,
        #container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
        anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
            anychart.data.loadJsonFile("data.php", function(data) {
                // create a data tree
                var treeData = anychart.data.tree(data, "as-tree", null, {
                    children: "children"
                });
                // map the data
                var mapping = treeData.mapAs({
                    actualStart: "start",
                    actualEnd: "end",
                    name: "nom"
                });
                // create a data tree
                // var mapping = anychart.data.tree(data, "as-tree");
                anychart.format.outputDateTimeFormat("ss'sec'");
                // create a chartec 

                var chart = anychart.ganttProject();

                // set the data
                chart.data(mapping);

                // set the container id
                chart.container("container");
                // set the data
                chart.dataGrid().fixedColumns(true);
                // chart.splitterPosition().hide();
                chart.dataGrid().column().enabled(false);
                chart.dataGrid().column(0).enabled(false);
                chart.getTimeline().elements().labels(false);
                chart.rowHoverFill("#ffd54f 0.3");
                chart.rowSelectedFill("#ffd54f 0.3");
                chart.rowStroke("0.5 #64b5f6");
                chart.columnStroke("0.5 #64b5f6");

                chart.dataGrid().column(0).enabled(false);

                var title = chart.title();
                title.enabled(true);
                title.text("Gantt Chart");
                title.fontColor("#64b5f6");
                title.fontSize(18);
                title.fontWeight(600);
                title.padding(5);

                scale = chart.xScale();

                // Set zoom levels.
                scale.zoomLevels([
                    [{
                            unit: 'millisecond',
                            count: 0
                        },
                        {
                            unit: 'second',
                            count: 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]);

                // configure the levels of the timeline header
                var header = chart.getTimeline().header();
                header.level(0).format("{%tickValue}{dateTimeFormat:ss} sec");
                header.level(1).enabled(false);
                header.level(2).enabled(false);
                chart.headerHeight(50);
                // initiate drawing the chart
                chart.draw();
                // fit elements to the width of the timeline
                chart.fitAll();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to know if it is possible not to reset the time so that the number of seconds can exceed 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it possible for seconds to pass the 59 mark, it is possible to make your program [bypass minutes and convert seconds straight to hours](https://playground.anychart.com/XEYZasqn/2). So it will adds up to 3599 seconds max.
This can be achieved by using [custom formatting functions](https://docs.anychart.com/Gantt_Chart/Timeline/Header#formatting_functions).

```
// configure the levels of the timeline header
           var header = chart.getTimeline().header();
// this function format appearance of seconds in a timeline header
           header.level(0).format((e)=>{
           let tickDate = new Date(e.tickValue)
           let currentSecond = tickDate.secondsInCurrentHour(e.tickValue)
           return currentSecond
           });
```